# ¿Por qué no guarda los datos?

Tags: prestashop

estoy intentando guardar los datos de un árbol de categorías y no me los guarda. Realmente no estoy seguro si no lo guarda bien o no lo recupera, pero creo que lo más probable es que no guarde. ¿Me podéis echar una mano?

```
protected function getConfigForm()
{
    return array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
            'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type'  => 'categories',
                    'label' => $this->l('Categorías'),
                    'desc'    => $this->l(''),  
                    'name'  => 'IT_CATEGORY',
                    'tree'  => array(
                        'use_checkbox'        => true,
                        'id' => 'IT_CATEGORY',
                        'selected_categories' => array((int)Configuration::get('IT_CATEGORY')),
                     )
                )
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            ),
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Set values for the inputs.
 */
protected function getConfigFormValues()
{
    return array(
        'IT_CATEGORY' => Tools::getValue('IT_CATEGORY', Configuration::get('IT_CATEGORY'))
    );
}

/**
 * Save form data.
 */
protected function postProcess()
{
    Configuration::updateValue('IT_CATEGORY', Tools::getValue('IT_CATEGORY'));
}
```

Comment: Enecesitamos mas información. Que pasa cuando haces submit? no puedes debbuguear? Te sale algún error?
Aclara mejor tu pregunta por favor

Comment: Cuando hago el debug veo que llegan los datos bien al postProcess, Tools::getValue('IT_CATEGORY') contiene un array con las categorías seleccionadas.

Pero cuando compruebo en el getConfigForm el Configuration::get('IT_CATEGORY') me devuelve false.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

El problema es que se devuelve un array y este hay que serializarlo para poder guardarlo.

Comment: SeNt, gracias por aportar. Sin embargo, es una respuesta de baja calidad. Puedes añadir más explicacion y ejemplos de como serializarlo? Mira [answer] para mejorar tu respuesta. Un saludo